# Was Joe being sarcastic after hearing about Jim?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, cinderella-man

There is a scene in *Cinderella Man* when Jim Braddock's manager Joe ask about the condition of Jim before the fight against Max Baer, it turns out that all of them are bad news . And then Joe says " What's the bad news, sunshine ?" Is this a phrase that uses commonly to express sarcasm ? What is this actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sarcasm, or irony.  Either way, it was meant for comic relief.  Like, "Can you tell me anything *worse* than what you've already told me?"  Same goes for using the nickname "Sunshine".  It's meant as irony/sarcasm.

Reminds me of a friend I had in high school who was chronically depressed.  Kinda like Eyeore from Winnie The Pooh.  Kids, being the cruel humanoids they are, used to call her "The Good News Bear" behind her back.  Same concept; using irony/sarcasm for comedic purposes.